# Can I prevent JLI_Launch from calling the caller's "int main (int argc, char *argv[])"?

Tags: java, macos, launch

Is there something simple I can do before calling `JLI_Launch` that would prevent its macOS bootstrapping behavior (which doesn't happen on linux)? Or do I have to continue reading more about the [invocation api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) and use something other than `JLI_Launch` (e.g., `JNI_CreateJavaVM`)? If you're wondering why such a complicated launcher, if I don't use its architecture (create no child processes), then dropping a file onto the app's icon (docked or not) opens the app but the app does *not* see the file drop event.

`JLI_Launch` behaves as if the code looks like this:

```
static int callCount = 0;
int JLI_Launch (/* parameters */) {
     if (callCount == 0) {
        callCount = 1;
        /* figure out what to tell the caller by creating argc,argv */
        main(argc, argv);
     } else {
        callCount = 0;
        // launch the VM
     }
     return 0;
}
```

The [appbundler project](https://github.com/TheInfiniteKind/appbundler) has [code](https://github.com/TheInfiniteKind/appbundler/blob/master/appbundler/native/main.m) that calls `JLI_Launch` after calling `dlopen` and `dlsym`. The `JLI_Launch` function then calls the appbundler's `main` which repeats everything, calling `JLI_Launch` again with the same arguments. The second time it calls `JLI_Launch`, the virtual machine runs the java code.

Other than some weird catastrophe that might happen on the second execution of the preparation code (e.g., choosing a version of Java other than what was chosen on the first execution), the amount of code that executes in preparation for calling `JLI_Launch` is significant. Executing it twice for the same result is wasteful.

Here's the MCV example. I know it's C instead of Objective-C, but this part doesn't matter. At least it doesn't seem to matter because it reproduces what I consider undesirable "bootstrappy" behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "jni.h"

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    // The code required to identify jargv is somewhat significant.
    char * jargv[] = { "test.exe", "Test", "Hello, world." };
    int jargc = sizeof(jargv) / sizeof(jargv[0]);
    // The code required to identify lib is significant.
    char * lib = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib";
    void * h = dlopen(lib, RTLD_LAZY);
    void (*launcher)() = dlsym(h, "JLI_Launch");
    puts("calling JLI_Launch");
    launcher(jargc, jargv,
             0, NULL, 0, NULL,
             "", "", "java", "java",
             JNI_FALSE, JNI_FALSE, JNI_FALSE,
             (jint) 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the java code that it will execute:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

CLG:

```
$ gcc -o test.exe -g -I $JAVA_HOME/include -I $JAVA_HOME/include/darwin test.c && ./test.exe
calling JLI_Launch
calling JLI_Launch
Hello, world.
```

Here's more proof using a debugger:

```
$ lldb test.exe
(lldb) target create "test.exe"
Current executable set to '.../test.exe' (x86_64).
(lldb) b main
Breakpoint 1: where = test.exe`main + 40 at test.c:6:12, address = 0x0000000100003da8
(lldb) r
Process 27252 launched: '.../test.exe' (x86_64)
Process 27252 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003da8 test.exe`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007ffeefbfeb00) at test.c:6:12
   3    #include "jni.h"
   4
   5    int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
-> 6        char * jargv[] = { "test.exe", "Test", "Hello, world." };
                   ^
   7        int jargc = sizeof(jargv) / sizeof(jargv[0]);
   8        char * lib = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib";
   9        void * h = dlopen(lib, RTLD_LAZY);
Target 0: (test.exe) stopped.
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100003da8 test.exe`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007ffeefbfeb00) at test.c:6:12
    frame #1: 0x00007fff20659621 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb) c
Process 27252 resuming
22 locations added to breakpoint 1
calling JLI_Launch
Process 27252 stopped
* thread #2, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003da8 test.exe`main(argc=3, argv=0x0000000100307a70) at test.c:6:12
   3    #include "jni.h"
   4
   5    int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
-> 6        char * jargv[] = { "test.exe", "Test", "Hello, world." };
                   ^
   7        int jargc = sizeof(jargv) / sizeof(jargv[0]);
   8        char * lib = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib";
   9        void * h = dlopen(lib, RTLD_LAZY);
Target 0: (test.exe) stopped.
(lldb) bt
* thread #2, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100003da8 test.exe`main(argc=3, argv=0x0000000100307a70) at test.c:6:12
    frame #1: 0x000000010015e31f libjli.dylib`apple_main + 84
    frame #2: 0x00007fff2063e950 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 224
    frame #3: 0x00007fff2063a47b libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 15
(lldb)
```

#### Postscript

A clue that the launcher code is unusual is that there are no header files anywhere having the string `JLI_`. I can find only `JNI_` function definitions and only in `jni.h`.

Another clue to the "bootstrappiness" is that `JLI_Launch` calls `main` with a different `argc` and `argv` that what `_start` used. But I fail to see why I would care because the code sends the very same values to `JLI_Launch` both times. If I thought feedback was necessary, then I'd live with it but I don't think there is.

Yet another clue is that on linux, at least with JDK 1.8.0_121, this behavior does not exist. I had to do some unexpected things to make it work:

```
1. call the executable bin/java instead of test.exe
2. soft link the JDK lib folder
```

Apparently, on linux, java calls dlopen to link its libraries based upon its knowledge of its home folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the backtrace I posted, I realized two things:

```
1. I see the name of the calling function, `apple_main`
2. I might be able to find its definition if I download Java SE 16's source code
```

I found the definition of `apple_main` in `src/java.base/macosx/native/libjli/java_md_macosx.m`:

```
/*
 * Unwrap the arguments and re-run main()
 */
static void *apple_main (void *arg)
{
    if (main_fptr == NULL) {
#ifdef STATIC_BUILD
        extern int main(int argc, char **argv);
        main_fptr = &main;
#else
        main_fptr = (int (*)())dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "main");
#endif
        if (main_fptr == NULL) {
            JLI_ReportErrorMessageSys("error locating main entrypoint\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    struct NSAppArgs *args = (struct NSAppArgs *) arg;
    exit(main_fptr(args->argc, args->argv));
}
```

The call to `pthread_start` hides (by definition) some of the call sequence (shown in stack form), which is this:

```
test.c: main (new main thread)
src/java.base/macosx/native/libjli/java_md_macosx.m: apple_main (new main thread)
src/java.base/macosx/native/libjli/java_md_macosx.m: MacOSXStartup (main thread)
src/java.base/macosx/native/libjli/java_md_macosx.m: CreateExecutionEnvironment (main thread)
src/java.base/share/native/libjli/java.c: JLI_Launch (main thread)
test.c: main (main thread)
```

I can now proceed.